# How to display two decimals in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am doing average of student marks in jQuery `row.append`

```
 row.append($('<TD></TD>').text(((item.Marks1 + item.Marks2 + item.Marks3) / 300) * 100));
```

I used like this its not working

```
 row.append($('<TD></TD>').text((Math.floor(item.Marks1 + item.Marks2 + item.Marks3) / 300) * 100));
```

This is average how to accept two decimals this type of formats please help me.

Comment: What the?? 3 up votes for this? Oh.. I forgot to see the OP's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 steps that will fix your problem:**

1. A `space` is not a valid character for a key in Javascript object (assuming that you have something like `Marks 1` as key in your object).  
      So, you need to replace `item.Marks 1` with something like `item.Marks1`.
2. Next, convert all of the marks values into Float values:

   `parseFloat(item.Marks1)`

   So, your code should look like:

`row.append($('<TD></TD>').text((Math.floor(parseFloat(item.Marks1) + parseFloat(item.Marks2) + parseFloat(item.Marks3)) / 300) * 100));`

**EDIT:** As suggested by others, you can apply `.toFixed(2)` at the end of the code line above to get 2 digits after the decimal point.

**EDIT2:** Added code snippet:

```js
var item = {
  Marks1: 100.10,
  Marks2: 100.105,
  Marks3: 100.201
}


var row = $('table');

var num = parseFloat(item.Marks1) + parseFloat(item.Marks2) + parseFloat(item.Marks3);

num = num / 300 * 100;

num = num.toFixed(2);

row.append($('<TD></TD>').text(num));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: I used tried your syntax also but it not showing any values

Comment: @meena Did you make the changes that I suggested to the Javascript object `item` that you are working on? Alternatively, you can try doing `item["Marks 1"]` or `item["Marks1"]`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: i edited my question there is no spaces in between marks1 then its fine working @Rahul Desai

Comment: @meena I am glad that my answer helped. Please mark this answer as accepted. Happy to help!

Comment: @meena I dont see the point of you using the `Math.floor` and then `.toFixed(2)`. Since you need to get the average, get rid of `Math.floor` and follow EDIT2 in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toFixed(2)`

```
 ((item.Marks1 + item.Marks2 + item.Marks3) / 300) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

### DOCS

> The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

Comment: `item.Marks 1 + item.Marks 2 + item.Marks 3` I am still scratching my head to understand this.. Did you??

Comment: see the docs.. :) `The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.`

Comment: `item.Marks 1` This would cause syntax error, even if we refer any docs. :)

Comment: you have incorrect variables ` ((item.Marks 1 + item.Marks 2 + item.Marks 3) / 300) * 100)` should return a number

Comment: it just values like 67,89,45 something like this. this values are getting from database

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra space from that you have in your object `item`. To access any property you need to use the object name with property without any spaces.
e.g, `item.Marks1`

Use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round any value to two decimal places:

In your case:

```
row.append($('<TD></TD>').text((((item.Marks1 + item.Marks2 + item.Marks3) / 300) * 100).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Did you copy that from my answer?

Comment: I just updated my answer by reviewing the documentation and tested and posted the working solution.

Comment: @meena Did you tried something like this:  **item.Marks[1] + item.Marks[2] + item.Marks[3]**

Comment: @meena If you are using `JSON` then what is your `JSON` format ?

Comment: @Joker it just column name in database i just used in this view also to display the values

Comment: @meena What are exactly your column names in db?